# Find point or points where a tangent plane is parallel to the plane z=0

Tags: multivariable-calculus

At which point (or points) on the ellipsoid $x^2 + 4y^2+z^2=9$ is the tangent plane parallel to the plane $z=0$

I am assuming that this occures at points $(0,0,-3)$ and $(0,0,3)$ because $z^2=9$ at $-3,3$

I should be able to caculate this using the gradient but I am not doing it correctly. Could you point me in the correct direction?

$$\nabla f = <2x, 8y, 2z>$$
I though that this should be equal to some multiple of the normal for $z=0$ which would be $<0,0,1>$

So I have  $$<2x, 8y, 2z> = c<0,0,1>$$

But this does not give me a point where $z=3$ or $z=-3$,

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, the required plane is normal to $(0,0,1)$. Yes the gradient is $(2x,8y,8z)$. So to make that parallel to $(0,0,1)$ you require $x=y=0$. Substituting that into the equation for the ellipsoid gives the two points $(0,0,\pm3)$.

Comment: I have just inserted the missing squared sign over the $z$ in your equation for the ellipsoid.